# How to return table name in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My Model.py

```
class Banana(models.Model):
nohdt = models.IntegerField()
isi_indonesia = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Banana'
def __str__(self):
    return self.isi_indonesia

class Mango(models.Model):
nohdt = models.IntegerField() 
isi_indonesia = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Mango'
def __str__(self):
    return self.isi_indonesia
```

My View.py

```
list = []
data = []
banana = Banana.object.all()
mango  = Mango.object.all()
list.append(banana)
list.append(mango)
for x in list:      #looping django-models
    for i in x:      #looping list in models
        tmp = {'no':x.nohdt, 'indo':x.isi_indonesia, 'table_name':???}
        data.append(tmp)
return render(request, 'index.html', {'data':data})
```

i have two models in model.py, in my view 'view.py' i use LIST to store data. Before i store, i loop list models, and loop value of models. And than i use tmp variable to keep information of 'nohdt', 'isi_indonesia', and 'name of model'.

How do i return name of model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access model name through class. I believe that you should loop with `i` in nested for loop not `x`.

```
for i in x:      #looping list in models
    tmp = {'no': i.nohdt, 'indo': i.isi_indonesia, 'table_name': i.__class__.__name__}
    data.append(tmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

for i in x:
    tmp = {'no': i.nohdt, 'indo': i.isi_indonesia, 'table_name': i.___str____()
}
    data.append(tmp)